# REALBasic and MySQL

Tags: mysql, realbasic

```
Dim db as MySQLCommunityServer
  db  =New MySQLCommunityServer
  db.host="127.0.0.1"
  db.port=3306
  db.databaseName="requesterdb"
  db.userName="root"
  db.Password=""

  Dim divisionID As String
  Dim supervisorName As String
  Dim lsupervisorTotal As Integer

  If db.Connect then


    dim r as RecordSet
    r=db.SQLSelect("select COUNT(*) As supervisorTotal FROM supervisorTable WHERE supervisorName='" + SupervisorTextField.Text.Trim + "'")

    if r<>nil and r.RecordCount>0 then
      while not r.EOF
        lsupervisorTotal     = r.IdxField(0) // Line with Error
        If lsupervisorTotal > 0 Then
          ' Check User Database and Insert If Needed
        End If

        r.MoveNext
      wend
    end if


  else
    MsgBox "Connection failed!"
  end if

  db.Close
```

The message says "There are several items with this name and it's not clear which one the call refers to lSupervisorTotal = r.IdxField(0)"

Above is the entire method and I don't know what the error is talking about.

Comment: Why would this be tagged VB, let alone VB6?  Just to grab attention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be r.IdxField(0).integervalue.  If it was a string it would be r.IdxField(0).stringvalue, .datevalue for a date, etc.

More info can be found in the online documentation at http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/RecordSet.IdxField

Comment: I upvoted this answer, though I would assume the code in the original post wouldn't correctly compile because it would expect an integer, whereas .IdxField would just return a database field.